# Fluent NHibernate One to Many Could Not Insert (foreign key constraint)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nunit, one-to-many

I have an error when testing my **Fluent NHibernate** mappings with **NUnit**. The problem arise when Fluent NHibernate tries to persist one object (**Contact**) in the database before persisting it's child (**ContactType**), thus giving me a foreign key violation:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not insert: Contact [...]
----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The INSERT statement conflicted with 
the FOREIGN KEY constraint [...] with table ContactType
```

**EDIT: Modified mapping of supplier to use Inverse() on the HasMany(). Also providing example of my mapping test.**

Now, the details.

I have a **Supplier** that has many **Contact** (one-to-many). The **Contact** has many-to-one relation with an other table, **ContactType**. Keep in mind that I am simplifying the models here so we can focus on the problem.

```
public class SupplierMap : ClassMap<Supplier>
{
        public SupplierMap() 
        {
            Table("Supplier");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
            HasMany(x => x.Contacts).KeyColumn("supplierId").Cascade.All().Inverse();
        }
}
public class ContactMap : ClassMap<Contact> 
{
    public ContactMap() 
    {
        Table("Contact");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
        References(x => x.ContactType).Column("contactTypeId");
        References(x => x.Supplier).Column("supplierId").Cascade.All();
    }
}
public class ContactTypeMap : ClassMap<ContactType> 
{

    public ContactTypeMap() {
        Table("ContactType");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
    }
}
```

Now when I test **ContactMap** the test runs just fine, no errors. When I run the SupplierMap test however, this is where I get the error. As expected, when I run the ContactMap test I get something like this in the trace:

```
INSERT INTO ContactType [...]
INSERT INTO Contact [...]
SELECT [...]
[...]
```

ContactMap test:

```
[Test]
    public void CanCorrectlyMapContact()
    {
        new PersistenceSpecification<Contact>(Session)
    .CheckProperty(c => c.Id, 1)
    .CheckReference(c => c.ContactType, new ContactType() { Id = 1, Archived = false, DescriptionEn = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_255, DescriptionFr = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_255, NameEn = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_50, NameFr = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_50 })
    .CheckReference(c => c.Title, new Title() { Id = 1, Archived = false, NameEn = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_255, NameFr = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_255, SortOrder = 0})
    .CheckReference(c => c.Region, new Region() { Id = 1, Archived = false, NameEn = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_128, NameFr = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_128, SortOrder = 0 })
    .VerifyTheMappings();
    }
```

For **SupplierMap** test however, I tries to insert **Contact** first (without trying to insert **ContactType**).

SupplierMap test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SupplierMapTest : DatabaseSetup
{
    private IList<Contact> tmpList;

    public SupplierMapTest()
   {
       Contact tmpContact = new Contact()
       {
           Id = 1,
           FirstName = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_128,
           LastName = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_128,
           Address = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_128,
           City = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_128,
           Email = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_128,
           FaxNumber = Constants.PHONE_NUMBER_50,
           PhoneNumber = Constants.PHONE_NUMBER_50,
           PostalCode = Constants.POSTAL_CODE_10,
           Archived = false
       };
       tmpContact.ContactType = new ContactType { Id = 1, Archived = false, DescriptionEn = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_255, DescriptionFr = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_255, NameEn = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_50, NameFr = Constants.LOREM_IPSUM_50 };
       this.tmpList = new List<Contact>();
       this.tmpList.Add(tmpContact);
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verify if the maping is successfull
    /// </summary>
    [Test]
    public void CanCorrectlyMapSupplier()
    {

        new PersistenceSpecification<Supplier>(Session)
        .CheckProperty(x => x.Id, 1)
        .CheckList(x => x.Contacts, this.tmpList)
        .VerifyTheMappings();
    }
```

This test results in the error at the top of this post.

Thanks in advance for your help. I can also provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
HasMany(x => x.Contacts).KeyColumn("supplierId").Inverse();
```

see [here](http://notherdev.blogspot.de/2012/04/nhibernates-inverse-what-does-it-really.html) for more information

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did try that. It was what made more sense to me at first but unfortunately even with Inverse() set on the SupplierMap side, the chain of action is 'INSERT Contact' first and fails right away.